# No bracket matching when using the proposed semantic tokens API in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using the VSCode (Insider) Semantic Tokens API to provide XSLT 3.0/XPath 3.1 syntax-highlighting.

The goal is to avoid using a TextMate grammar as this is really too limited ([VSCode Issues - 216](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/216)) for syntax highlighting XSLT/XPath. There are performance issues with TextMate grammars also.

My implementation extends the [Semantic Tokens sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/semantic-tokens-sample) and returns tokens with the 'operator' tokenType for characters `{`, `(`, `[`, `]`, `)` and `}`.

I've modified settings.json as follows for the Extension Development Host but this makes no difference:

```
{
  "[typescript]": {},
  "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
  "git.autofetch": true,
  "[XPath]": {
    "editor.matchBrackets": "always"
  }
}
```

I hoped that bracket matching for these token types would be automatic, but this doesn't appear to be the case. Is there a workaround for this? Am I using the wrong tokenType? Should I put in a feature request?

Comment: Considering that this feature isn't even released yet, GitHub issues do seem like a better place to discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Language Configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide) has a brackets property that can be set:

> Brackets definition:
>   When you move the cursor to a bracket defined here, VS Code will highlight that bracket together with its matching pair.

```
{
  "brackets": [["{", "}"], ["[", "]"], ["(", ")"]]
}
```

The use of this is illustrated in the [language-configuration-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/language-configuration-sample).

Comment: I found the solution. I had failed to find the right part of the documentation.